# AngularJs, about the digest cycle

Tags: angularjs

I'm starting a project with AngularJs (v 1). And that was nice until I started to wonder about the quality of my project. Because now I try to avoid abusing the `$scope`, `$scope.$apply`, `$scope.broadcast` and other nice things like that.

So now, all of my _controller_s are using `var vm = this;` instead of `$scope` and my directives are using callbacks instead of `$scope.$apply`. The problem I have is that the changes are not updated. 
While the usage of `$scope.$apply` from a model attribute inside a directive was automatically updating the views it is not the case with a callback to a controller that update the model attribute. Then a workaround is to use _event_s but since `$scope.$broadcast` and his friends is not recommended, I have to create my own observers.

But at the end, I have the feeling to loosing the cool features of AngularJs. And started to wonder how are professionnals doing.

- How do you ensure that changes made to a model are updated to a view ?
- How you ensure that changes made to a model from a view are updated to another (master-details) ?

Thanks a lot for your advices.

Comment: This is a fairly broad question. For general advice, the [Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) was a big help for us.

Comment: Much too broad. Provide a concrete minimal example of something that doesn't work as you expect. With code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calbacks do not trigger angular digest. But events do not trigger digest either. The thing is that you usually want to call digest after:
-user click 
-user input 
-http response 
-...
And for all these cases there are built-in functions that trigger digest: $http, ng-click, ng-change, etc.

Comment: So @Petr Averyanov, explicit calls to `$scope.$apply`is not that bad ?

Comment: explicit calls to $scope.$apply is not badat all, it is just not for beginners - you need to be 100% sure in what you are doing